# javaScript:Void(0) refreshes the page when dynalimically creating component using $A.createComponents

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript

I'm trying to make a link dynamically using `$A.createComponents` but it tends to refresh the page even if I use

`javascript:void(0)`

Previously this was working fine but in the latest release this is giving a problem.

```
$A.createComponents([

                            ["aura:html",{
                                "tag" : "a",
                                "HTMLAttributes" : {"id":"" ,
                                                    "class": "",
                                                    "href":"'javascript:void(0);'"
                                                   }
                            }],
                            ["aura:html",{
                                "tag" : "label",
                                "body":"",
                                "HTMLAttributes" : {"id":"" ,
                                                    "onclick":""
                                                   }
                            }],
                            ["aura:html",{
                                "tag" : "span",
                                "HTMLAttributes" : {"id":"",
                                                    "onclick":""
                                                   }
                            }]

                        ],
                                            function(components, status, errorMessage){


                                                if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                                                    var a = components[0].get("v.body");
                                                    a.push(components[1]);
                                                    a.push(components[2]);
                                                    components[0].set("v.body", a);

                                                    var container = component.find("aaa");
                                                    var body = container.get("v.body");
                                                    body.push(components[0]);
                                                    container.set("v.body", body);
                                                }
                                                else if (status === "INCOMPLETE") {
                                                    console.log("No response from server or client is offline.")
                                                    // Show offline error
                                                }
                                                    else if (status === "ERROR") {
                                                        console.log("Error: " + errorMessage);
                                                        // Show error message
                                                    }
                                            }
                                           );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am new in Lightning, but as per my understanding you can achieve your requirement via :

```
["aura:html",{
   "tag" : "a",
   "HTMLAttributes" : {"id":"" ,
                    "class": "",
                    "onclick": component.getReference("c.handleClick")
                   }
}],
```

And `handleClick` method would be like:

```
 ({
   handleClick: function (component, event, helper) {
     event.stopPropagation();
  }
})
```

Comment: can't we just remove href attribute? Read out this doc : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_supported_html_tags_a.htm

Comment: Yea this works fine .Thanks for answering If u could just edit ur ans ill vote it as correct ans

Comment: Answer corrected. Glad to help you!